# Changing the vhost for solr on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, vhosts

I've just installed tomcat and Solr on my server. Currently I access Solr through www.example.com:8080/solr/select/?q=...`www.example.com:8080/solr/select/?q=...`
I was however wondering if it would be possible to alter the automatically set vhost and get a url like `search.example.com/select/?q=..`

I've been looking for some time, but can not seem to find the defining vhost file.

Best Regrads

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `defaultHost` in your `tomcat`'s `server.xml` file.

For details have a look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html#server.xml) and [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/engine.html).